# PHP Send notification to remote phone

Tags: php, notifications, push

I'm actually doing a booking page for a php application,
what i need is to tell the owners when someone books a date sending them a notification. Is there any API?

Comment: How **exactly** does someone book a date using your application? I'd assume a form submission, in which case I would recommend simply saving the booking into a database. From here you can either use an API to send a TXT or make use of an email address as 'middleware'.

Comment: There's a PHP form, i'm actually storing data into a database. What i need to do is to tell the customers to check the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a SMS from a web app you can use: https://www.twilio.com/